# Is it possible to copy files from blob storage / file share into an FTP within an ADF?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I have a couple of pipelines in ADF, which in the end will produce some files. These files are currently being stored in file shares and blob storages. However, I'd like to move them inside a FTP server.

As of now, I have create a linked service to that FTP and a dataset that points to the FTP and the folder that I want to use to upload the files. However, when I use the activity "Copy Data" and use this dataset, I get the error "the linked service in sink dataset does not support sink".

As far as I understand, this is only possible with a SFTP, which is not valid for me, it must be an FTP (technical limitations).

Can you provide me some guidance here?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can call Azure Logic App activity which contains SFTP and FTP connectors + Azure Storage connectors:

http://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2018/06/execute-logic-apps-in-azure-data.html